# Using `groupadd` in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, and a quick peek at `/etc/group` reveals

```
$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
libuuid:x:101:
netdev:x:102:
crontab:x:103:
syslog:x:104:
ntp:x:105:
ssh:x:106:
```

When I tried to add `staff`, I got an error message as I would expect (being that `staff` is already defined with gid `50`).

```
$ groupadd --gid 20 --non-unique staff
groupadd: group 'staff' already exists
```

The unexpected part is when I tried to add a user with the `staff` group.

```
$ useradd --groups staff --no-create-home --no-user-group --non-unique --root /projects/ --uid 502 username
useradd: group 'staff' does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here? It don't believe it is Docker specific, but I just wanted to make mention in case it was important.

Comment: More useful than telling us you're using "docker" would be to tell us what distribution (and version) you're running inside your docker container.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `--root` argument.  If you look at the [useradd man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/useradd.8.html), you'll note that `--root` specifies a `chroot` directory:

```
-R, --root CHROOT_DIR
           Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the configuration
           files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
```

That means that when you pass `--root projects`, the `useradd` command will be looking for `/projects/etc/passwd`, `/projects/etc/group`, etc.  Those don't exist, which leads to the "does not exist" error.

I wonder if you actually meant `--home-dir` or `--base-dir` instead of `--root`?

Comment: Thank you! You helped me clear a big misconception. Now I get `No passwd entry for user '502'`, when I try `su 502`. What else did I mess up?

Comment: `su` wants a username, not a numeric userid.

Comment: Is there a similar utility that uses a uid?

Comment: Why not just use the username you created with the `useradd` command? It looks as if `sudo -u #uid` will do what you want (as in `sudo -u '#502' ...`).